# can a variable in Python get 2 values using 'or'

Tags: python-3.x, variables, pyserial

I read response from serial port using ser.read_until('condition1')
Want to break reading when one of two responses received. A question is
can a variable 'response' get 2 conditions with 'or'? Meaning following:

```
response = ser.read_until(b'Successful').decode() or ser.read_until(b'Failed').decode()
```

Comment: You will only get the second option ("failed") if the first part (before the or) is of NoneType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way `or` works in Python is it evaluates the left side, and if that is a falsey value, it evaluates the right side and returns it. (This is called short-circuiting, where the execution halts early if the other value is not needed).

In boolean algebra, since A or B is true if A is true, regardless of B, then we don't need to evaluate B if we see that A is already true. If A is false, then A or B is equal to B.

Therefore, Python (and many other languages with non-strict typing) decided that `a or b` would evaluate `a`, then if that is true, return it, and if it is false, return `b`.

In this case, the second value will only evaluate if the first gives `False`, `None`, etc. In this case, you probably want to read the data stream manually and check for either `Successful` or `Failed` to appear yourself, since this will read until `Successful` is found, evaluate it, and then when you try to read `Failed`, it might not work because the data stream will have already moved past the `Failed` since it was trying to look for a `Successful`.